# why i can get the body object when its DOM parsing no finish?

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, bower

after reading [How Brower work](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Speculative_parsing),i know the  the [HTML parsing flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XSHK.png);

But in this case,why the body dom object can get? 
(i make an break point on the script which get the body tag object);

As i know during html parsing,Dom buliding will be block when parser parsing the script; it is because of bower Speculative parsing or Browsers' error tolerance？
(ps:i am using chrome bower)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>Before</div>
    <script>
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    </script>
    <div>After</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to get the `body` tag from JavaScript because your `script` tag is inside the body itself, this means the `body` tag is already available to the browser'engine.

In case your JavaScript would be added in the header (which is also quite typical) you won't be able to get the `body` tag. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        console.log(body); // undefined
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Before</div>
    <div>After</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Speculative parsing is technique which allow the browser to speed up HTML parser by delegation this operation on a separate thread. Basically it parses ahead the HTML tree construction while your scripts are being downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.you are right .i reviewed the article "how browers works" and figure out that html parser will add the  tag token to the parse tree  When the > tag is reached.

Comment: @tao.weng I'am glad it helped you out. Happy coding :)